# Categories in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-category

I have written the following category on NSString:

```
 @interface NSString (Checks)

 -(BOOL) isUppercase;
 -(BOOL) containsStr: (NSString *) str;

 @end;

 @implementation NSString (Checks)

-(BOOL) isUppercase
 { return [[NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[self         characterAtIndex:0]]
 }
 -(BOOL) containstStr: (NSString *) str
 { return [self rangeOfString:str].location != NSNotFound;
 }
@end
```

I get missing context for method declaration, expected method body, @end must appear in an Objective C context errors in the .h file, why is that?

Comment: Note: I have also written something for NSString (it works) and the first line in the header-file is: #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h> |

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have a semicolon after `@end`. Also make sure that you import the Foundation framework:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSString (Checks)

- (BOOL)isUppercase;
- (BOOL)containsStr:(NSString *)str;

@end


#import "NSString+Checks.h"  // or whatever your .h is called.

@implementation NSString (Checks)

- (BOOL)isUppercase {
    return [[NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet] 
           characterIsMember:[self characterAtIndex:0]];
}

- (BOOL)containsStr:(NSString *)str {
    return [self rangeOfString:str].location != NSNotFound;
}

@end
```

Comment: also don't forget to import the .h file in the .m fie

Comment: I have removed the semicolon and imported the Foundation framework but still the same problem; I have also imported the .h file into the .m file.

Comment: Is this a project started from an app template? Do you have the Foundation framework linked in your project?

Comment: Note the typo: `containstStr` in the implementation should read `containsStr`.

Comment: Yes. And you missed a semicolon in your first method.

Comment: You should also prefix all methods with something unique to yourself.   In general, categories like this are discouraged because the lead to maintenance headaches.